# How to create camera calibration opencv dll for Labview

Tags: c++, opencv, labview, camera-calibration

How can I create camera calibration dll for Labview? I'm using Visual Studio. I want to perform calibration that is explaned here:
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html[cameraCalibrationOpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html)
Soo when dll will be caled from Labview it will take imput image for calibration and calibrate itself and return calibrated image.

Problem discovered so far:
1. My Labview is 32-bit, OpenCV is 64-bit. 
2. Don't know much about camera calibration and how to use reference link, so need help here.

Comment: I don't see the relationship between VS and Labview?

Comment: Ja_cpp, what do You mean by that. I want to use perspective camera calibration dll to fix issues that are apearing in one of LV programs. So for that I need dll for camera to self calibrate. This is not the rule that VS has to be used...

Comment: I believe that you need to develop that yourself to take snaps from the camera and when it is done then the program of calibration get launched automatically to read the images and calibration the camera, that's all the steps. The link you shared is only for calibration manually, you need to prepare the photos yourself and launch the program..etc